# Type conversion in ada

Tags: ada

I have a package where I convert a string to an integer with this :

```
param: integer;
begin
param:= Integer'Value(param_string);
```

My question is verysimple, i would like to do the same thing, but with a generic package. The generic type is TypeElement. However i can't do this :

```
param: TypeElement;
begin
param:= TypeElement'Value(param_string);
```

The error is 'prefix of "value" attribute must be scalar type'

Is there a trick ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic formal type you provide for TypeElement must represent a scalar type.

If you're declaring it as private, e.g.:

```
generic
   type TypeElement is private;
```

then that's not going to work, because there's no guarantee that TypeElement is going to be a scalar type, which, as you've discovered is required to use the 'Value attribute. You need to use one of the generic formal type representations for discrete types, as listed in the [Ada LRM 12.5.2](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-12-5-2.html#S0266).

For example:

```
generic

   type Type_Element_Discrete is (<>);
   type Type_Element_Signed_Int is range <>;
   type Type_Element_Mod is mod <>;
   type Type_Element_Digits is digits <>;
   type Type_Element_Delta is delta <>;
   type Type_Element_Delta_Digits is delta <> digits <>;

package Gen_Convert is

   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Discrete;
   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Signed_Int;
   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Mod;
   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Digits;
   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Delta;
   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Delta_Digits;

end Gen_Convert;
```

Specifying the appropriate formal type also ensures that the instantiator of the generic provides a valid type. Here's the corresponding body demonstrating the 'Value conversions:

```
package body Gen_Convert is

   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Discrete is
   begin
      return Type_Element_Discrete'Value(Param_String);
   end Gen_Convert;

   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Signed_Int is
   begin
      return Type_Element_Signed_Int'Value(Param_String);
   end Gen_Convert;

   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Mod is
   begin
      return Type_Element_Mod'Value(Param_String);
   end Gen_Convert;

   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Digits is
   begin
      return Type_Element_Digits'Value(Param_String);
   end Gen_Convert;

   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Delta is
   begin
      return Type_Element_Delta'Value(Param_String);
   end Gen_Convert;

   function Gen_Convert (Param_String : String) return Type_Element_Delta_Digits is
   begin
      return Type_Element_Delta_Digits'Value(Param_String);
   end Gen_Convert;

end Gen_Convert;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my problem is that the TypeElement can be an integer or a string. I have to set the type to private to do that, no ?

Comment: The 'Value attribute isn't valid for an Integer, so there's no way to construct a generic that will rely on that to extract an integer value from a TypeElement. (And yes, TypeElement would have to be a private formal type to accept either an Integer or String actual type). However, if the generic also required a "Value_Of" function: "with Value_Of(T : TypeElement) return String" then the instantiator would supply the TypeElement and a Value_Of function (which could use 'Value) and your generic package would just invoke Value_Of() to convert from String to Integer, or just return the Integer.

Comment: In the above comment I mistyped the return type of the suggested Value_Of() function, it should be: `with Value_Of(T : TypeElement) return Integer`. (Ran out of time to edit the comment.)

Comment: It is also worth checking your floating/fixed point types with 'valid as not all bit patterns are valid floating point numbers.

Comment: Generally, unless someone has voted the comment up, I fix that problem by copying the comment text to the clipboard, deleting the comment, then resubmitting it (with the fix).